# Is there any way to solve normality problem in R?

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to do multiple regression test in R.
I have made a model but I have found some problems.
I have done homogeneity of variance test and the variance was not found to be heterogeneous.
But I have done normality test and p-value was very low. It was about 2e-16.
Here's the data and my script.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Should I convert my data? Should I use boxcox?
Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: The model explains such a uselessly small proportion of the total variance (see the R² values) that normality of residuals becomes a secondary concern.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that..!! Then I wonder is it okay to do multiple regression in this situation.. You're already a lifesaver..but I hope you could give me a hand again. Thank you very much!

Comment: Multiple regression might be okay. It's just that your model does not include a good predictor. If you don't even explain 1 permille of the total variance, the model is worthless because (i) it misses at least one important predictor or (ii) the data is basically completely random and relationship with your predictors is probably spurious or due to influential values.

Comment: Wow..! I didn't expect this kindness..!! I'll do the predicting part tomorrow and I hope I could find a way to explain the variance. Really hope your day goes well! :)

Comment: The outlier with "age" appears to be a data issue. Do you have a missing code such as -9 that hasn't been recoded as missing?